# the Monotonicity of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let  $$g(x)=-x \frac{\cos(\frac{A}{x})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})}+x.\cot(\frac{\pi}{x})$$ be a function with respect to $x$  defined on $(\frac{3}{2},+\infty)$

and $A\in \mathbb{R}$ a constant, such that $$\frac{-\pi}{2}.x\le A \le \frac{\pi}{2}.x$$

shows  that $g(x)$ is increasing on $(\frac{3}{2},+\infty)$

the derivative gives me a bit difficult term to work with

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand the nature of what 'A' is, the inequality seems to be a function of 'x' so is A a function of 'x'?

Answer (score 1):

$$f=x \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{x}\right)-x \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{x}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{A}{x}\right)$$
Let $x=\frac 1y$ to make
$$f=\frac{\cot (\pi  y)-\csc (\pi  y) \cos (A y)}{y}$$ Compute $f'_y$ and
$$f'_x=f'_y \times \frac{dy}{dx}$$